# Gif изображение в Android Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, gif

Есть метод для появления Gif

```
public void GifStart()
    {
        webGif.LoadUrl(string.Format("file:///android_asset/AgifLoading.gif")); 
        //проигрывается только 1 раз
    }
```

Метод для остановки Gif

```
    public void GifStop()
    {
       webGif.ClearAnimation(); //это не работает
    }
```

Ну и метод в котором показывается Gif

```
private async Task NickParser()
{
   GifStart();
   //остальной код
   GifStop();
}
```

Хочу сделать, чтобы при запуске метода, в определеном месте появлялось Gif изображение и работало до тех пор, пока асинронный метод не вернул результат.

Такой себе кастомный прогресс бар. Как реализовать?

Comment: Офтопик: в яве есть конвенция имен, которая говорит, что методы должны называться startGif() и stopGif(), а не GifStart(), GifStop(). На работоспособность кода имена, разумеется, никак не влияют, но лучше сразу привыкать к правильному.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Хочу сделать, чтобы при запуске метода, в определеном месте появлялось Gif изображение и работало до тех пор, пока асинронный метод не вернул результат.

Использовать события. Например,

```
public class Loader
{
    public event EventHandler StarLoadingData;
    public event EventHandler EndLoadingData;

    public async Task LoadingData()
    {
        StarLoadingData?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        EndLoadingData?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Подписываемся на события таким образом:

```
loader = new Loader();
loader.StarLoadingData += Loader_StarLoadingData;
loader.EndLoadingData += Loader_EndLoadingData;

private void Loader_StarLoadingData(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GifStart();
}

private void Loader_EndLoadingData(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GifStop();
}
```

По окончании работы с объектом не забывайте отписываться от событий:

```
loader.StarLoadingData -= Loader_StarLoadingData;
loader.EndLoadingData -= Loader_EndLoadingData;
```

Подробнее о событиях можно почитать [здесь](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.14.php).

Для анимации попробуйте библиотеку [Lottie](https://github.com/martijn00/LottieXamarin). Поддерживается Xamarin и Xamarin.Forms. [Здесь](https://www.lottiefiles.com/) можно найти готовую анимацию для данной библиотеки.